# Comparing row values in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have a product column
Something like this

```
P-2400
R453
P-5632
P-5632
Q5639
```

I want the result like this

```
1
1
1
2
1
```

In excel we use this formula
If(a2=a1, b1+1,1)
Column b is the result column
Column a is product column
I am unable to do it in powerbi.  Thanks

Comment: [RANKX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax) can be used for that.

Comment: See eg: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-add-Row-number-over-partition-by-Customer-DAX-or-M-query/m-p/567725#M267935

Comment: Thanks Luuk and David. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-add-Row-number-over-partition-by-Customer-DAX-or-M-query/m-p/567725#M267935 This solution worked.